# Find out if someone is logged in gmail, yahoo and facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I am working on a web application where I have to tell user that he is logged in `gmail` or `yahoo` or `facebook` account. I think this can be done using `cookies`. 

How to find out it? 

what is the cookie name of these accounts, so that I can check their presence

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gmail can be tested by linking to a public image in your own google account. Facebook can be tested by loading your own profile, as a script. Both of these links will succeed if the person is logged into the respective service and fail if they are not. Afraid I don't know specific details for Yahoo but I imagine a similar technique would work.

A good article on this is located here, I believe the techniques both still work:

https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Comment: Very interesting, albeit somewhat shady, but not tooo shady. Atleast this isn't the permanent cookie that's self replicating.

Comment: Definitely questionable as to if this is something you should do, but the technique is awesomely inventive.

Answer (score 4):

This is inherently meant to be IMPOSSIBLE. What you are asking for would be by definition, a cross site scripting attack, everything about a web browser is supposed to stop you from doing this.