# How to check if users are in their Yahoo! / Gmail account

Tags: php, gmail, yahoo, loginstatus

Most of the users of my website have entered Yahoo! and Gmail emails. I want to add a page to my administrator section that show which one of them are now logged in in their email accounts to give the admin the option to send them an email.

Is it possible to implement such thing?

Comment: Email will get there regardless of whether they are currently logged in or not. Why do you want to spy on your users?

Comment: I don't know about yahoo but in gmail, you can use OpenAuth. Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5903837/496841) is a answer on same issue.

Comment: Because the users have to do some assigned works,but some of them are lazy and the admin wants to alert them at the time they are on the internet to check their works.

Comment: I think if this question had the email stuff *removed* it would be stronger. E-mail is e-mail; it is the accounts (which just happen to be associated with e-mail) and "online status" is really what is being asked here. I'm still not sure if that'd get anywhere, though :)

Comment: umm... but I remember there was some code that checked if a user is online in Yahoo! or not. It used to display support service status of a for example hosting website that display online/offline icon of Yahoo! messsager on the page.

Comment: If yahoo&gmail do not provide an API for finding that out, then the only way for you to find out is if you find a security hole in the browser. So good luck with that.
Also: I keep my gmail open ALL the time, that does not mean I'm actually in my email ...

Comment: I'm asking for an API and I agree that if somebody is in his email it doesn't show he is at the desk too, but it is a command from the commander !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out if someone is logged in gmail, yahoo and facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903733/find-out-if-someone-is-logged-in-gmail-yahoo-and-facebook)